# During iOS application tests, how can I access a singleton instance in the host application?

Tags: ios, swift, testing, xctest, kif

I'm writing an iOS app with Swift, and we are using Parse for our backend. I'm working on some acceptance tests, and have mocked the Parse API using [OHHTTPStubs](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs).

I'm writing a test that taps through our login form and logs in a given user. In the view controller, we are calling the `PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground` function. Inside the completion block, I'm calling `println(PFUser.currentUser())`, and I can see that it is set correctly.

However, when I call `println(PFUser.currentUser())` from my test case, it is still nil. I want to make sure that the user is being signed in, and that their username is correct.

The tests are application tests which are injected into the host application, and are written with KIF. So I think the tests may contain their own separate `PFUser` singleton instance, instead of accessing it on the host application. So I need to figure out how to gain access to the `currentUser()` inside the main app.

Is there any way I can tell my tests to use the `PFUser` class from the main app?

If you think this should normally work out of the box, what kind of mistakes should I look for in my code? (e.g. bridging headers, build settings, etc.)

Comment: Posting your code would be useful to help you answer this question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what to post. I definitely don't want to post the entire source code, since it is private. What code would you like to see specifically?

Comment: A quick note is that I found some interesting information here, regarding the difference between Non-Hosted and Hosted tests: https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs/wiki/A-tricky-case-with-Application-Tests

I think it is a very similar issue (my test bundle has it's own instance of PFUser).

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution. I needed to access the class from the main bundle, and I did so by adding this line to a helper file in my test target:

```
let AppUser: AnyClass! = NSBundle.mainBundle().classNamed("PFUser")
```

This lets me perform checks such as `AppUser.currentUser() == nil`, and call functions like `AppUser.signOut()` on the main bundle, instead of in the test bundle.

The reason is that the main bundle and test bundle are separate, and classes are not shared between them. [This OHHTTPStubs wiki page](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs/wiki/A-tricky-case-with-Application-Tests) goes into more depth about the difference between hosted and non-hosted tests in Xcode.

Comment: P.S. I'm not too sure why people were downvoting the question. Maybe it was too obscure or technical. Either way, I hope this helps someone in the future.